# How to Organize related applications into git repo's?

Tags: database, git, github, version-control, development-environment

What is the decision tree to know when to split a suite of related and/or cohesive applications into git repo's and/or branches?  Should I keep each app in a repo? Or all app's & dependencies in a single repo?  Or something in-between?

answer [How should I organize multiple related applications using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382666/how-should-i-organize-multiple-related-applications-using-git) claims that a repository per project is appropriate, but does not give clues as to what a project would be.

And then there's the question of dev, test, integration test, and production checkouts when the git repo's are split. Answer [how do you organize your programming work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669318/how-do-you-organize-your-programming-work) lists some branch/tag options, but ignores the multi-app details.

There's also the DB schema! incremental definition of the schema helps, but again, where would one keep this definition if the DB spans back-end and front-end app's?

Some examples I've been pondering:

1. a front-end web app and it's back-end CGI/DB: one repo or two?
2. a set of web back-ends that use features from other back-ends
3. a set of front-end app's that share CSS and jquery plug-ins
4. selenium scripts that test front-end features across dependent code - in the front-end app repo or the dependent code repo?

If I want to work on a single app, it's hard (well, tedious and error prone) to check out a directory of a repo, so I have to check out the entire git tree (or at least clone the whole tree), so that implies that git is not really built for keeping all the app's & dependencies in a single tree.

But if I want to keep each of the projects (app's, frameworks, dependencies, doc trees, CSS) in it's own repo, then I run into chasing my tail for dependency resolution, that is, I don't know which version of each app are compatible.  I think git tags are a good way to go, if only I could move them to newer versions that maintain compatibility.

When app's split or merge -- as happens often with refactoring models down to baser models -- can i move the git history of just those files to another git?  I don't see how to do this, so that leans towards a single repo for it all.

If I develop a new feature across app's, it would be nice for branches to represent features.

I think I want a repo of repo's -- does that exist?

Answer (score 1):

This is about using a **component approach**: a component being a coherent set of files which have their own history (own set of branches, tags and merges).
It should include only what cannot be generated (although the db schema can sometime be added to the repo, as seen in "[What is the right approach to deal with Rails db/schema.rb file in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6450396/6309)". You still can generate it though, as shown in "[What is the preferred way to manage `schema.rb` in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931533/6309)", to avoid [needless conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738283/6309))

A component can evolve without another one having to evolve. See "[Structuring related components in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322295/6309)".
That is the main criteria which allows you to answer: "X and Y: one or two repos?".
You can [split a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository) [into two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two) later, but be aware that will change their history: other contributor will need to reset their own repo to that new history.

You can group those different components repos in one with submodules, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21072554/6309) (that is the "repo of repos", or, if you want to have only one repo, in [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/), as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24709789/6309).